# Combining arrays of arrays in ruby

Tags: ruby

Beginner Ruby question here: What's the most idiomatic way to combine two arrays of arrays in Ruby?

```
a = [[0, 0, 0]]
b = [[1, 1, 1]]
```

I'd like to find c such that

```
c = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

I've been able to solve this with a loop, but can't seem to find a way that "feels" correct.

Comment: `chain` is cool but `a + b` is the most straightforward and transparent solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[chain](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-chain) is a recently added method on Enumerables

```
a = [[0, 0, 0]]
b = [[1, 1, 1]]
p a.chain(b).to_a # => [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: What a cool method, particularly because it returns an enumerator! I love answers that tell us about new methods, this one having made its debut in v2.6.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just concatenation [Array#+](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-2B), `a + b`?

```
a = [[0, 0, 0]]
b = [[1, 1, 1]]


c = a + b
c #=> [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One method would be:

```
c = [a.flatten] + [b.flatten]
```

although you could also:

```
c = [a.first] + [b.first]
```

I expect there are a few other too.

Comment: `c = [a.flatten] + [b.flatten]` could be simplified to `c = a + b`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [concat](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-concat):

```
a = [[0, 0, 0]]
b = [[1, 1, 1]]

c = a.concat(b)
c #=> [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

But please note it appends the elements of `b` to `a`, which might be less expensive than `a + b` (new array by concatenating `a` and `b`) but modifies the `a`.

```
a #=> [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
b #=> [[1, 1, 1]]
c #=> [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: The OP has indicated that a new array (`c`) is desired, rather than `a` being mutated.